# GRUB2 - Select OS based on time (RegExp or other method)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bash, grub

I'm trying to make grub2 boot to Ubuntu when in a certain hour interval and otherwise to Windows. I'm trying to do this by editing /boot/grub/grub.cfg and changing which OS is being used as default on `set default`. Grub2 runs on it's own shell-like scripting language and it doesn't have bash `date +%H` that I can use to see which hour i'm in and set the default OS accordingly. What the shell-like scripting language that grub runs on DOES have is:

A [date](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/date.html#date) command that prints something like:

`2021-03-10 18:36:29 Thursday`

And a [regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/regexp.html#regexp).

What I would like to know is how to use the `regexp` command and what is the regex expression that will return the hour from the `date` command.

If there is another method that can do what I'm trying to do that you think will be easier please tell me.

## **Answer**

My question was how to get the hour using regex in grub2, but what I would like to do was to make grub2 boot on the correct OS based on time. After a lot of research I found a better way to solve this problem.

1. Open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file using your favorite editor.
2. Search for the `set default` command. This is the command that defines the default OS.
3. Delete the command that appears on the else branch.
4. Paste this code.

```bsh
# My script to boot on Ubuntu when on specific hours
# and days, use 'sudo update-grub' to use default grub.cfg
insmod datehook
if [ ! ("${WEEKDAY}" == "Saturday" -o "${WEEKDAY}" == "Sunday") ]; then
    if [ "${HOUR}" -ge 10 -a "${HOUR}" -le 17 ]; then
        set default="0"
    else
        set default="4"
    fi  
else
    set default="4"
fi
```

5. Save and the next time you reboot these rules will be applied.

## **About the snippet**

`insmod datehook` makes the following environment variables accessible: `$YEAR`, `$MONTH`, `$DAY`, `$HOUR`, `$MINUTE`, `$SECOND`, `$WEEKDAY`.

To understand the if-else's sintax you can refer to [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/test.html#test)

I hope this can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My findings are different than yours.

Specifically, in the
[GNU GRUB Manual 2.04](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html)
I have found references to the two missing functions:

> [**16.3.20
> date**](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#date)
>
> ```
>     Command: date [[year-]month-day] [hour:minute[:second]]
> ```
>
> With no arguments, print the current date and time.

And also:

> [**16.3.62
> regexp**](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#regexp)
>
> ```
> Command: regexp [--set [number:]var] regexp string
> ```
>
> Test if regular expression *regexp* matches *string*. Supported
> regular expressions are POSIX.2 Extended Regular Expressions. If
> option `--set` is given, store *number*th matched subexpression in
> variable *var*. Subexpressions are numbered in order of their opening
> parentheses starting from ‘1’. *number* defaults to ‘1’.

According to this documentation, and assuming that `date` returns a string
such as `2021-03-19 10:11:12`, then regexp should skip 11 characters
and extract the next two, so the command might look like:

```
regexp --set hour '.{11}(.{2})' "`date`"
```

If this works as in normal bash, the hour might be found in the variable
`hour`.

But it would be up to you to test and see, because there are several unknown
areas, such as when the hour is less than 10, does it still have
two digits, and more. Only testing will find all these small details.

Comment: I linked these references in my post. I just don't know how to use them to do what I want to do. Could you tell me or point me to the answer?

Comment: I have added more to my answer, but as I don't have experience with this environment, this is just an educated guess. Testing is still required for the small details.

Comment: echo $hour prints nothing after executing the regexp, I also tried date whithout any quotations and still nothing.

Comment: Do you mean that `date` doesn't work at all and gives an empty string?

Comment: I believe that the regexp command that you wrote should put the first appearance of the regex on the string in the hour variable. `date` returns something like `2021-03-19 10:11:12 Thursday`.

Comment: Possibilities that unfortunately need checking: (1)  `number` is required so the command should be `regexp --set 1:hour '.{11}(.{2})' "`date`"` (2) The shell does not allow embedded commands so the `date` is better [set](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#set) first to a variable, (3) This regexp string is not supported and should be simplified.

Comment: Sadly the first two sugestions didn't work. And I couldn't find a manual for POSIX.2 Extended Regular Expressions so I could look up to see if I'm writing the regex string right.

Comment: I found a [reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions). It seems there is an alternative to `( )` : `\( \)`.

Comment: The regex `\d{2}(?=:\d{2}:\d{2})` gives me the hours on a string like `2021-03-19 10:11:12 Thursday` when I use it on [this](https://www.regextester.com/99203) website. I just don't know if it's the same regex type as the one that grub uses, but it still don't work on grub to get the hour to a variable using `regexp --set`. :(

Comment: It's a weird software. Try to use `\( \)` instead of `( )`.

Comment: Still nothing. :/

Comment: In the idea that this shell is very minimalist, try instead of `.{11}(.{2})` to use the ultra-basic expression `...........(..)` with `regexp --set 1:hour`. Try it on a hardwired string to see if it works, then try to get the `date` result into a variable and use that in the `regexp` command. Maybe try `mydate = $(date)` if the backquote syntax is not supported.

Comment: So this regex worked on a hardwired string as you recommended I tried but not on the date command. Looking for a way to put the date command on a variable so I could try to use it in the regexp command I have come along with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84140/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-grub2) question that gives me a better solution for my problem. As you gave me the solution to my question I'll mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks a lot harrymc.